# REGEX: find URL with specific words/pages

Tags: regex

I have the current regex exp:

```html
http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```

Which retrieves all the urls from a file, but I need it to only get the urls with a specific page, let's say *page-to-find* and I can't seem to do it without having the expression to add to a second group and I only want it natively in one group instead of two, as direct as possible.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: `http[s]?://` → `https?://`. No need for the character class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a page what does it end in?  .asp?  .php? .aspx? .htm? .html? (Something else?)

Try this for a start:

```
 http[s]?://.*page-to-find
```

Comment: Thank you, I was overcomplicating a bit.

Comment: No problem!  We all do that sometimes  :)  Glad to help!  :)